# Requests lose their folder assignment

Tags: postman

On occasion, a collection's grouping of requests into folders breaks and many requests are shown at the top level of the collection. It may be caused by my having the collection open on two machines at the same time, but I'm just guessing.

- Does anyone else have this experience?
- Does anyone know how to prevent it?

When that happens, the only fix I know is to drag-n-drop each request, one at a time, into the proper folder. This is tedious.

- Is there a quicker way to get multiple requests into folders?

Comment: What do you use, desktop app or chrome extension? Which version? Which steps do you do to get this error? Could you give us a screenshot?

Comment: I use version 4.9.2, OS X (10.12.2), Chrome 55.0.2883.95. I can't supply steps to get the error other than 'wait for it to happen again'.  I can't supply a screenshot, it's full of client-confidential stuff.